# How do i fix this error of 'simple_permissions' on flutter?

Tags: android-studio, plugins, flutter, androidx

There is an error when I run the code including simple_permissions on flutter project.

```
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:10: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                 ^
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, perm, 0);
        ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:163: error: cannot find symbol
        return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable ContextCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(registrar.activity(), permission)) {
                ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
C:\Users\ria\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(registrar.context(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':simple_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

*******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Any luck on this issue? I just happened upon it after upgrading to Android X.

Comment: downgrade a version of simple_permkssions might work

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same issue, after some searches I found this repository.

```
https://github.com/tq-systems/simple_permissions
```

This repository solved the AndroidX compatibility issues.
import it into the pubspec.yaml like that:

```
dependencies:
  simple_permissions:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/tq-systems/simple_permissions.git
```

Comment: This repo still has some issues with null safety and v2 embedded fr Android, i solved  that in this repo : https://github.com/moda20/simple_permissions

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I solved it with these step

**Step 1 =>** Update your android studio to lastest version
[download here](https://developer.android.com/studio)

**Step 2**
Uninstall your android studio and install the new with new **setting**

**Step 3**
Add the **Flutter plugin**

**Step 4**
Add this to your depences in **build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
}
```

**Step 5**
Run this command

> flutter packages get

To update your packages and gradles

It worked fine for me.