# How to export csv in file from app using flutter? without using simple permission plugin, and permission_handler plugin

Tags: flutter

I want export .csv file to download folder from app. my app is developing using flutter. I try to use simple permission and permission handler plugin but both have problem/conflict with other plugins...so can i export without using both plugins....?

references:

```
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-reading-and-writing-files-example
https://icircuit.net/create-csv-file-flutter-app/2614
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074889/how-do-i-fix-this-error-of-simple-permissions-on-flutter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin
```

Error when i clicked export button:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/export.csv' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Error when I try to use simple permissions plugin:
same error with : [How do i fix this error of 'simple_permissions' on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074889/how-do-i-fix-this-error-of-simple-permissions-on-flutter)
But the steps in guides said need to uninstall and reinstall android studio...do I have other choices?

```
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See  for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
```